# Trying to access nested element in XML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm new to data science and I'm not sure if this is the right thing to ask but I'm trying to get an attribute from an XML dataset using beautiful soup. Here is how the structure looks like:

[image]

What I need to have is the `<text>` which is Kosher Meal and this is what I've written so far:

```
meals = b.find_all(attrs={'refs':'Meal'})
for meal_name in meals:
    print(meal_name.text)
```

This gives me a nice clean list but the print statement prints this:

> SRVC-MEAL-PRICE-6-BA0183Meal: Kosher MealKosher Meal0T2BA018311

So do I need to split and clean data or is there a way to access that `<text>` out of it?

Comment: Can you post the XML data so we can copy/paste it?

Comment: A basic rule here is to not post images of text, copy/paste the actual text.  For almost all stuff you copy/paste, use code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

`soup.find_all()` returns all the meal XML tags, and not the meal names as you would expect. For each meal tag that is found, you need to independently search for the `Name` tag inside:

```
meal_tag_list = b.find_all(attrs={'refs':'Meal'})
for meal_tag in meal_tag_list:
    meal_name = meal_tag.find("Name").text
    print(meal_name)
```

If you want to extract the descriptions, you can use a similar approach:

```
meal_tag_list = b.find_all(attrs={'refs':'Meal'})
for meal_tag in meal_tag_list:
    description_tag_list = meal_tag.find("Descriptions")
    for description_tag in description_tag_list:
        description_text = description_tag.find("Text").text
        print(description_text)
```